# Rewrite path/*/* in firebase.json

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to rewrite url in the format `/myfunction/{ANY_STRING}/{ANY_STRING}/`
to a firebase function. I wrote the following rewrite rule in `firebase.json` :

```
{
  "source": "/myFunction/*/*",
  "function": "myFunction",
},
```

Is it the right way to write the rule?

Comment: Does it work the way you expect?  If so, then it's correct.  If it's not working the way you expect, your question should show your debugging details.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the Firebase rewrite rule you have written looks correct. It should rewrite the URL in the format of `"/myFunction/{ANY_STRING}/{ANY_STRING}/"` to the "myFunction" Firebase function.

The `"//"` segments in the source parameter of the rule are wildcard placeholders that match any two path segments after `"/myFunction/"`. These segments will be passed as parameters to the `myFunction` Firebase function as variables that can be used within your Firebase function code.

Just make sure that you have a Firebase function named `myFunction` defined in your Firebase project, which should handle the incoming request with the two wildcard parameters.